Why is it true that $\lfloor \sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n+1}\big\rfloor = \big\lfloor \sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n+2}\rfloor$
I would like to prove that
$$\big\lfloor \sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n+1}\big\rfloor = \big\lfloor \sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n+2}\big\rfloor$$
for all positive integers $n$.
Interestingly enough, this is not true for $\sqrt[3]{n}$ with a counter-example to be $n = 15$.
I wonder why that is true, and where in the proof it goes wrong for $\sqrt[3]{n}$.

Possibly helpful: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/760330/42969 (and the linked questions), where it is proven that $\lfloor \sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n+1}\rfloor = \lfloor \sqrt{4n+1}\rfloor$.

It can be shown that either $\big\lfloor \sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n+1}\big\rfloor = \big\lfloor \sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n+2}\big\rfloor$ or $\big\lfloor \sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n+1}\big\rfloor+1 = \big\lfloor \sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n+2}\big\rfloor$ holds for an integer $n$.

@Prem: No, it is not (verified with PARI/GP).

Suppose otherwise. Then there exists an integer $k$ such that
$$\sqrt n+\sqrt{n+1}<k\le\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n+2}$$
Squaring both sides:
$$n+2\sqrt{n(n+1)}+(n+1)<k^2\le n+2\sqrt{n(n+2)}+(n+2)$$
$$2n+1+2\sqrt{n(n+1)}<k^2\le 2n+2+2\sqrt{n(n+2)}\tag{1}\label{eq1}$$
Now,$$\sqrt{n(n+1)}>n$$
and
$$\sqrt{n(n+2)}<\sqrt{n^2+2n+1}=n+1$$
Putting these into $(1)$:
$$2n+1+2n<k^2<2n+2+2(n+1)$$
$$4n+1<k^2<4n+4$$
So $k^2\equiv 2$ or $3\bmod4$, which is impossible.

That's a very clear proof. Thumbs up!

Computer calculations suggest that it is also true for the 4-th root. Does this method also work for that? I couldn't work it out.

Neither can I :-)

@MR_BD yes, it can be made to work for 4th roots. By the same argument $(\sqrt[4] n+\sqrt[4]{n+1})^4>16n+1$, since expanding gives one term that is exactly $n$, one that is exactly $n+1$, and $14$ other terms that are in between. Because $\sqrt[4]{n}$ is concave, $\sqrt[4]n+\sqrt[4]{n+2}<2\sqrt[4]{n+1}=\sqrt[4]{16n+16}$.

and since the only fourth powers mod $16$ are $0$ and $1$, you're done. (This last is what goes wrong for $\sqrt[3]{n}$: there are lots of cubes mod $8$.)

It's not true for $\sqrt[8]{n}$, with $n=1525$ being a counterexample.

@EspeciallyLime Thanks for the great comments. You can make it into an answer for better visibility

It could be proved using similar argument as proving $\lfloor \sqrt{n} + \sqrt{n+1} \rfloor = \lfloor \sqrt{4n+2} \rfloor$ in this post.
The reasoning goes like this: we first claim that $(\sqrt{n} + \sqrt{n+2})^2 \in (4n+3, 4n+4).$ Letting $y = \sqrt{n} + \sqrt{n+2}$, we will have $y \in (\sqrt{4n+3}, \sqrt{4n+4}).$ Thus $\lfloor y \rfloor$ should be an integer whose square is the first perfect square less than or equal to $4n+3$. But $4n+3$ is never a square. So $\lfloor y \rfloor = \lfloor \sqrt{4n+2} \rfloor$
Actually, both should be equal to $\lfloor \sqrt{4n+1} \rfloor$ also since $(4n+2)$ is never a perfect square.
For the $\sqrt[3]{n}$ case, I have not checked but I guess if you follow this logic, the bounding range might be larger and it might fit many perfect cubes in the range.

Formatting tip: instead of \sqrt(Expr) use \sqrt{Expr}.

@DávidLaczkó Thanks! edited.

I was able to show $(\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n+2})^2 \in (4n+2,4n+4)$. How did you get $4n+3$ as the lower bound? @Pond-nj

$(\sqrt{n} + \sqrt{n+2})^2 = 4n+2 + 2\sqrt{n(n+2)} - 2n$ where we have $2\sqrt{n(n+2)} - 2n > 1$ from $4n(n+2)>4n^2 + 4n +1$. @Sam

Let consider $n$ going from $m^2$ to $m^2+2m$, then, since $\left(m+\frac12\right)^2=m^2+m+\frac14$, we need to check

for $n=m^2$ up to $n=m^2+m-1$

$$\big\lfloor \sqrt{m^2+m-1}+\sqrt{m^2+m}\big\rfloor =2m=\big\lfloor \sqrt{m^2+m-1}+\sqrt{m^2+m+1}\big\rfloor \tag 1$$

for $n=m^2+m$

$$\big\lfloor \sqrt{m^2+m}+\sqrt{m^2+m+1}\big\rfloor =2m+1=\big\lfloor \sqrt{m^2+m}+\sqrt{m^2+m+2}\big\rfloor \tag 2$$

for $n=m^2+2m$

$$\big\lfloor \sqrt{m^2+2m}+\sqrt{m^2+2m+1}\big\rfloor =2m+1=\big\lfloor \sqrt{m^2+2m}+\sqrt{m^2+2m+2}\big\rfloor \tag 3$$
Next we would have $n=m^2+2m+1=(m+1)^2$ which is covered by $(1)$ and so on.
Since $(1)$, $(2)$ and $(3)$ hold, the given identity holds.

For identities $(1)$, LHS is trivial and RHS is true by Bernoulli's inequality since
$$\sqrt{m^2+m-1}+\sqrt{m^2+m+1}<2m+1$$
Identities $(2)$ are true since for the LHS
$$\sqrt{m^2+m}+\sqrt{m^2+m+1}>2m+1$$
ideed by squaring both side
$$\sqrt{m^2+m}\sqrt{m^2+m+1}>m^2+m \iff \sqrt{m^2+m+1}>\sqrt{m^2+m}$$
For identities $(3)$, LHS is trivial and RHS is true by AM-GM
$$\sqrt{m^2+2m}+\sqrt{m^2+2m+2}<2m+2$$
$$\iff \sqrt{m^2+2m}\cdot \sqrt{m^2+2m+2}<m^2+2m+1$$
